# Graph API post comment with photo attachment

Tags: python, facebook, python-3.x, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get my script to post a comment on all comments of a parent post that meet a certain requirement.  I am able to get the text to post reliably but I can't seem to get the photo attachment to show up.  I'm programming in Python3 and using the Facebook-sdk library to assist.

When reading the Graph API documentation I found the following fields described on the comments edge:

> attachment_id
>
> An optional ID of a unpublished photo (see no_story field in /{user-id}/photos) uploaded to Facebook to include as a photo comment. One of attachment_url, attachment_id, message or source must be provided when publishing.
>   (string)
>
> attachment_url
>
> The URL of an image to include as a photo comment. One of attachment_url, attachment_id, message or source must be provided when publishing.
>   (string)
>
> source
>
> A photo, encoded as form data, to use as a photo comment. One of attachment_url, attachment_id, message or source must be provided when publishing.
>   (multipart/form-data)

My code is currently formatted as such (I've provided partial code relevant to this issue):

```
my_dict = {
    0: ('file_1.JPG', "Some text for file 1"),
    1: ('file_2.jpg', "Different text for file 2"),
    2: ('file_3.JPG', "More different text for file 3"),
    3: ('file_4.JPG', "A fourth bit of text for file 4.")
}

comments = api.get_object('PAGE.NUMBER.HERE?fields=posts{comments}')
com_index = comments['posts']['data'][0]['comments']['data']
photo_id = my_dict[x][0]
my_image = 'file:///Users/filepath/{}'.format(photo_id)
text = my_dict[x][1]
api.put_object(com_index[com_index]['id'], "comments/comments", source=(my_image, 'image/jpg'), message=text)
```

I have tried both with and without the 'image/jpg' argument in the source tuple.

Instead of using 'source' I've also tried:

```
attachment_url=card_image
attachment=card_image
```

When using attachment_url I get an invalid url error; when using the other parameters the text always is posted but the photo is not posted.

Lastly, I've tried changing the edge to be a /photos edge of the comment instead of the /comments edge of another comment, but still no luck (as below):

```
api.put_object(com_index[comment]['id'], "comments/photo", source=(my_image, 'image/jpg'), message=text)
```

What is the proper method to post a reply that has a photo attachment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `{objet-id}/comments` is depreciated since version 2.10. Check [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.10/object/comments/).

Comment: I did see that warning at the top AFTER a bunch of reading, lol. Bummer. But I'm still able to get the comments to post the text, so it still seems to work, I just can't get the photos to attach properly. Would it make sense that I'm successful to get the comments to post text if the /comments edge was deprecated?

Comment: After investigating, it looks like I may have to implement my script to send a private reply (something I had initially considered). Is it possible to pass an attachment or photo argument to a private reply?  The documentation does not list an attachment field so I presume not, but you can send a photo in fb messenger I believe: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.10/object/private_replies

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a Python guy, but perhaps this is working anyway ;)

```
my_dict = {
   0: ('file_1.JPG', "Some text for file 1"),
   1: ('file_2.jpg', "Different text for file 2"),
   2: ('file_3.JPG', "More different text for file 3"),
   3: ('file_4.JPG', "A fourth bit of text for file 4.")
}

comments = api.get_object('PAGE.NUMBER.HERE?fields=posts{comments}')
com_index = comments['posts']['data'][0]['comments']['data']
photo_id = my_dict[x][0]
my_image = 'file:///Users/filepath/{}'.format(photo_id)

photo = open(my_image)
text = my_dict[x][1]

api.put_object(com_index[com_index]['id'], "comments/comments", source=photo.read(), message=text)
photo.close()
```

Comment: Thanks, I had considered creating an image object using Pillow to pass an image object to the API. That would be a similar approach to your suggestion, so I'll try it . I am just assuming I need to pass a file path instead of object but it's worth trying.

Comment: My mistake, I meant I hadn't thought of passing it an object with a method to display the object. But I'll try